Did Shakespeare get his name from Psalm 46?
There is a theory going around that Shakespeare adopted his name from the Bible. Alleged evidence for this claim is that Shakespeare was in King James' service during the preparation of the King James Bible, and was generally considered to be 46 years old in 1611 when the translation was completed. There are a few extant examples of Shakespeare's actual signature, and on at least one occasion he signed it 'Shakspeare', which divides into four vowels and six consonants, thus '46'. The 46th word from the beginning of Psalm 46 is "shake" and the 46th word from the end (omitting the liturgical mark "Selah") is "spear" ("speare" in the original spelling) ( Courtesy: Wikipedia/Psalm 46 )                So,is it true that Shakespeare got his name from Psalm 46 ?

I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't have anything to actually do with Christianity.

It has been suggested that Shakespeare may have translated, or influenced the translation, of Psalm 46 in such a way as to include his own name. As Stephen Disraeli says, Shakesperare did not choose his own surname. Arguably he could have arranged for it to appear in the way that it does in the KJV translation of Psalm 46. I have heard that suggested but do not know how plausible it is; but if there is any connection it would be that way round, how his name got into the psalm, not how the psalm gave him his name.

This is an historical question, and needs an historical answer.
William was the grandson of a Richard of the same surname.His own line can't be traced back further, but the surname is centuries older in England.
https://www.houseofnames.com/shakespeare-family-crest
In short, he did not choose the name for himself.

You have a point, Stephen Disraeli. In fact the verses in Psalm 46 that correspond to shake and spear read : though its waters roar and foam and the mountains quake with their surging.[c] 4 There a river whose streams make glad the city of God, 5 God is within her, she will not fall; God will help her at break of day. 6 Nations are in uproar, kingdoms fall; he lifts his voice, the earth melts. 7 The Lord Almighty is with us; the God of Jacob is our fortress. 8 Come and see what the Lord has done, 9 .... He breaks the bow and shatters the spear; – Shakespeare simply associated the words .
